# How to read a Lucene index?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I'm working on a project for which I want to build a tag cloud by reading a Lucene index and pruning it down. I didn't set up the Lucene engine, it was someone else in the team, now I just want to read its index. Do you how to do that in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you need to look for is how to use **IndexReader** class, the *.terms()* method will give you back all the terms in the index.

Comment: This looks even better! Is there any chance you know how to access the index if it's in the WEB-INF/index folder? I use OpenCMS and that's the default location.

Comment: from the API docs.
Concrete subclasses of IndexReader are usually constructed with a call to one of the static open() methods, e.g. open(String).

Answer (score 15):

Not sure what you mean by "reading" an Index:

1. If you want to query it you can use IndexSearcher class.
2. IndexReader allows you to open the index in read mode.

If you want to view the contents of the index, you can use [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/)

Comment: Thanks! Luke seems like the solution I was looking for!

Comment: BTW you can initialize an `IndexSearch` like so:

    `IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(pathToIndex))));`

`IndexSearcher` also has a constructor that accepts an `ExecutorService`, you should look in to that for searching different segments in parallel.

Answer (score 11):

You do it like this -

```
IndexReader r = IndexReader.open( "prdb_index");

int num = r.numDocs();
for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if ( ! r.isDeleted( i))
    {
        Document d = r.document( i);
        System.out.println( "d=" +d);
    }
}
r.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do this:

```
File indexDirectory = new File("YourIndexLocation");
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory));
return reader.maxDoc(); //return total docs in index
```